# Javascript not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a PHP form validation function that I developed in chrome and now will not work in firefox or Opera.

The function checks to see if a section of the form is blank and shows and error message. If there is no error then then the form submits through `document.events.submit();`

CODE:

```
function submit_events()
        {

            //Check to see if a number is entered if the corosponding textbox is checked
            if (document.events.dj_card.checked == true && dj_amount.value==""){

                //Error Control Method
                //alert ('You didn\'t enetr an Amount for DJ\'s Card!');
                var txt=document.getElementById("error")
                txt.innerHTML="<p><font color=\"#FF0000\"> You didn\'t enetr an Amount for DJ\'s Card!</font></p>";                 
            window.document.getElementById("dj_card_label").style.color = '#FF0000';

            //Reset
            window.document.getElementById("company_amount_label").style.color = '#000000';
            window.document.getElementById("own_amount_label").style.color = '#000000';


            }else{

                document.events.submit();

            }
```

The `document.events.submit();`does work across all my browsers however the check statements do not.

If the box is not ticked the form submits. If the box is ticked it does not matter whether there is data in the dj_amount.value or not. The form will not submit and no error messages are displayed.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Can you please post the contents of the form? :)

Comment: @Dr.Molle @Ivo Wetzel Cheers guys. Was just a silly mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some things I noticed. Not sure if it will solve the problem, but you need to fix some of these; some of them are just observations.

- dj_amount is not declared nor referenced; my guess is you mean `documents.events.dj_amount`
- You should put a `;` at the end of every statement in javascript, including the end of `var txt = document.getElementById("error")`
- You don't need to escape the string in the `txt.innerHTML` line; you only need to escape like quotes, such as `"\""` or `'\''`, not `"'"` or `'"'`
- You don't need the window.document referenced; document will do in almost all cases

**EDIT** - As Guffa points out, FONT is an old and deprecated element in HTML. It's not the cause of your problems, but modern markup methods mean you don't need it. Consider omitting and applying the style to the paragraph tag instead.

See edits below.

```
function submit_events() {
    //Check to see if a number is entered if the corosponding textbox is checked
    if (document.events.dj_card.checked == true && document.events.dj_amount.value == "") {
        //Error Control Method
        //alert ('You didn't enetr an Amount for DJ\'s Card!');
        var txt = document.getElementById("error");
        txt.innerHTML = "<p style=\"color: #FF0000;\"> You didn't enter an Amount for DJ's Card!</p>";
        document.getElementById("dj_card_label").style.color = '#FF0000';

        //Reset
        document.getElementById("company_amount_label").style.color = '#000000';
        document.getElementById("own_amount_label").style.color = '#000000';
    } else {
        document.events.submit();
    }
}
```

Consider Firebug so that you can see and log to console javascript errors and messages:

http://getfirebug.com

Comment: Cheers mate. yes the issue was i was calling an undfinied event when I should have been using document.getElementById("dj_amount").value==""

Comment: Cool. :D Thank you for checking the answer (you'd be surprised how many don't).

Comment: Actually you don't strictly need to terminate JavaScript statements with a semicolon but you should do it anyway just because it's so much better.

Comment: @Neil - You're right, I was getting it confused with PHP. I definitely think it's a good practice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To have minimal changes in code, just add this line before the first `if` statement:

```
var dj_amount = document.forms["events"].elements["dj_amount"];
```

However your code need serious optimization let us know if you're interested.

Edit: here is the optimization. First the "small" things - instead of whatever you have now for "error" container, have only this instead:

```
<p id="error"></p>
```

Now add this CSS to your page:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #error { color: #ff0000; }
</style>
```

This will take care of the red color, instead of hard coding this in the JS code you now control the color (and everything else) from within simple CSS. This is the correct approach.

Second, right now you are submitting the form as response to `onclick` event of ordinary button. Better approach (at least in my humble opinion)  is having submit button then overriding the form `onsubmit` event, cancelling it if something is not valid. So, first you have to change the function name to be more proper then have proper code in the function. Cutting to the chase, here is the function:

```
function ValidateForm(oForm) {
    //declare local variables:
    var oCardCheckBox = oForm.elements["dj_card"];
    var oAmoutTextBox = oForm.elements["dj_amount"];

    //checkbox cheched?
    if (oCardCheckBox.checked) {
        //store value in local variable:
        var strAmount = oAmoutTextBox.value;

        //make sure not empty:
        if (strAmount.length == 0) {
            ErrorAndFocus("You didn't enter amount for DJ's Card!", oAmoutTextBox);
            return false;
        }

        //make sure it's numeric and positive and not too big:
        var nAmount = parseInt(strAmount, 10);
        if (isNaN(nAmount) || nAmount < 1 || nAmount > 1000000) {
            ErrorAndFocus("DJ's Card amount is invalid!", oAmoutTextBox);
            return false;
        }
    }

    //getting here means everything is fine and valid, continue submitting.
    return true;
}
```

As you see, when something is wrong you `return false` otherwise you return true indicating the form can be submitted. To attach this to the form, have such form tag:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return ValidateForm(this);">
```

And instead of the current button have ordinary submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
```

The code will be called automatically.

Third, as you can see the function is now using "helper" function to show the error and focus the "misbehaving" element - this makes things much more simple when you want to validate other elements and show various messages. The function is:

```
function ErrorAndFocus(sMessage, element) {
    var oErrorPanel = document.getElementById("error");
    oErrorPanel.innerHTML = sMessage;

    document.getElementById("dj_card_label").style.color = '#FF0000';
    document.getElementById("company_amount_label").style.color = '#000000';
    document.getElementById("own_amount_label").style.color = '#000000';
}
```

Last but not least, the "new" code also makes sure the amount is positive number in addition to check its existence - little addition that will prevent server side crash.

Everything else is pretty much self explanatory in the function: naming conventions, using local variables.... most important is have as little redundancy as possible and keep the code readable.

Hope at least some of this make sense, feel free to ask for clarifications. :)

Comment: Yes I would be interested. I am still quite new to web development and am always looking to learn better methods.

Answer (score 1):

I believe one of the above answers would solve your problem. For future reference, although it might not be suitable for your project, please know that writing forms and javascript feedback is much easier and faster when you use a library like jQuery.

Comment: Thanks mate. I will deferentially be using a library in my next project.

Answer (score 0):

You should bring up the error console so that you see what the error actually is.

Lacking that information, I can still make a guess. Try some less ancient HTML code; the parser can be picky about code you add to the page using innerHTML:

```
txt.innerHTML="<p style=\"color:#FF0000\"> You didn\'t enetr an Amount for DJ\'s Card!</p>";
```

Comment: I called an event instead of using getElementById. For some reason it work in Chrome. Cheers for your help.